# WebStorm - autocomplete

Tags: node.js, webstorm

Autocomplete does not work correctly for me, for example :

[image]

I tried adding node.js globals but I don't see it in the settings :
[image]

Any idea how I can fix this?

Notes :

- When I run the app everything runs fine.
- I am using nodejs 4.2.4 for Windows 64 bit on Windows 10.
- I am using "Empty Project".
- I am using WebStorm 11.

Comment: *"I tried adding node.js globals"* It's now part of "Node.js Core". Have you tried "File | Invalidate Caches..." and restart IDE? -- may help.

Answer (score 4):

#### In WebStorm 11

You need to enable the **Node.js Core library**.

Go to `Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Node.js and NPM` and click "Enable" under **Code Assistance**.

Comment: This helped me enable autocomplete for node.js. This should be enabled by default in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

To enable code assistance for Node.js core APIs (and that means you’ll get smart code completion, parameter info and navigation to source code), the only thing you need to do is go to Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js and npm and click Enable under Code Assistance.

An even quicker way to do the same is to use the Enable Node.js Core library quick-fix. Press Alt+Enter on the highlighted usage of one of the Node.js core modules in the code and then press Enter.